# Jetty6 service and administrator rights

Tags: service, jetty, admin, windows-xp

How do I determine if my Jetty6-service run with administrative rights?

I need to setup Jetty on my XP dev box to run as a service. 
http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Win32Wrapper

It installs OK and I can see the Jetty6 Service in windows services manager.

But when I try to start it I get this error in the log file:

```
STATUS | wrapper  | 2010/02/26 10:17:10 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2010/02/26 10:17:10 | Error occurred during initialization of VM
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2010/02/26 10:17:10 | Too small initial heap for new size specified
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2010/02/26 10:17:10 | JVM exited while loading the application.

from above link:
Note: The above application (Jetty-Service.exe) must execute with administrator rights otherwise, it fails.
```

I do have local administrative access to my XP dev box. 
And when I run the jetty server as standalone from cmd.exe then it works fine. 
(java -jar start.jar etc/jetty.xml)

Does anyone know how to solve this problem / where to look?
/Thanks.

Comment: I think I solved it. 
I changed \bin\jetty-service.conf, 
wrapper.java.initmemory=30
   (it was not related to admin rights after all.....)